# In a Rails 4 controller, thing_params.delete(:something) is not deleting the :something key-value pair

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I have the following in a controller:

```
# app/controllers/things_controller.rb

def create 
  kind = thing_params.delete(:kind)
  detail_attributes = thing_params.delete(:detail_attributes)
  @detail = Detail.create(kind, detail_attributes)
  @thing = current_user.things.build(thing_params)
  ...
end


private

def thing_params
  params.require(:thing).permit(
    :name,
    :position,
    :kind,
    { detail_attributes: [ :detail_category_id, ... ] },
end
```

Both `kind` and `detail_attributes` are being properly set in the first two lines of the `create` method. However, `thing_params.delete(:kind)` isn't removing the "kind" key-value pair from the `thing_params` hash. Same with the `:detail_attributes` one.

What can I do so they are removed from the `thing_params`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `thing_params`, you're getting a copy of a bunch of stuff from `params`. Then you delete `:detail_attributes` from that copy. Then you call `thing_params` again to get another fresh copy. You should be doing it more like this:

```
clean_params = thing_params
detail_attributes = clean_params.delete(:detail_attributes)
#...
@thing = current_user.things.build(clean_params)
```

That way you'll only be working one copy of the cleaned up `params` rather than two.